# Is there a way to get a mobx observable variable address in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to change a variable value given to a component through props inside of a function in this component.
I cannot get the value of the observable to change (even when passing the variable through parameter) so I wanted to know if I could retrieve the observable address to modify it directly this way.

```
@observer
class Exemple extends React.Component {
  @observable Nom

  @action onChangeNom = newValue => {
    this.Nom = newValue //I want to have something similar to this function inside the component but it would take the value to update and the newValue as parameters
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <FormComponent //this is where I call my component
        ContainerStyle={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
        }}
        ObjArray={[
          {
            InputDivStyle: { width: '49%', marginRight: '2%' },
            FieldType: 'textInput',
            FieldStyle: { borderColor: this.missingLastName ? 'red' : COLOR_NOT_BLACK },
            OnChange: this.onChangeNom,
            Placeholders: 'Ex. Durand',
            Value: this.Nom, //this is the value I want to change inside the component
            InputTitle: 'Nom',
          },
        ]}
      />
    )
  }
}

@observer
class FormComponent extends React.Component<props> {
  render() {
    const { ObjArray, ContainerStyle } = this.props
    return (
      <div style={ContainerStyle}>
        {ObjArray.map((e, index: number) => {
          const { Disabled, FieldStyle, InputDivStyle, FieldType, Placeholders, OnChange, Value, InputTitle } = e
          return (
            <>
              <div style={InputDivStyle ?? {}} key={index + 'Input'}>
                {InputTitle && (
                  <>
                    <Label medium>{InputTitle}</Label>
                  </>
                )}
                <GenericInput
                  disabled={Disabled ?? false}
                  placeholder={Placeholders ?? ''}
                  style={FieldStyle ?? {}}
                  type={FieldType ?? ''}
                  value={Value ?? ''}
                  onChange={evt => {
                    OnChange(evt.target.value)
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default FormComponent
```

My concern is that I want to be able to change the value inside of the component without having to create a function for each value (if there was multiple objects in ObjArray for example. (I have already tried by passing the value as parameters inside of the component but it doesn't update it outside that's why I want to be able to change the value directly at the memory address where it is stored (like you can do in C with pointers)).

Comment: I'm afraid you need to post some code example or debugging details, otherwise it is not clear what is the problem. Or https://codesandbox.io/ reproduction, that would be the best

Comment: I edited the post, I hope it is clear enough now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to change the value directly at the memory address where it is stored

It is not possible in Javascript, you can't "pass-by-reference" (in original meaning) and so you can't change values like that.

The easiest way would be to have function like that:

```js
  @action onChange = (key, newValue) => {
    this[key] = newValue 
  }
```

You pass it into component with a key and then invoke like that:

```
  onChange={evt => {
    // Or you can use InputTitle instead of key
    OnChange(key, evt.target.value)
  }}
```

That way you don't need to create lots of functions for every value

Comment: I'm gonna stick with this thanks ! Although I'm kind of sad because I wanted be able to handle the changes directly in the component but I don't think it is possible